# Why is my cursor empty even if item exists and attributes were correct?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have been trying to query some items in my table, but nothing is getting returned. I know I only have 3 items in my table, but my selections are valid attributes so that I can get something.

My crafts in the table have five attributes on them and if an attribute don't exist, it will be 0 in the table. I am doing queries like "crafts must have 2,3,0,0,0 because the last three attributes are 0.

However, nothing is getting returned even though my selection exists in the table. I am not sure why is it doing that.

I would appreciate any help!

My code is below this line:

```
// To get data from DB by querying the items selected
    public String getData(int firstSelection, int secondSelection, int thirdSelection,
                          int fourthSelection, int fifthSelection)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String firstSelectionStr, secondSelectionStr, thirdSelectionStr, fourthSelectionStr, fifthSelectionStr;

        firstSelectionStr = Integer.toString(firstSelection);
        secondSelectionStr = Integer.toString(secondSelection);
        thirdSelectionStr = Integer.toString(thirdSelection);
        fourthSelectionStr = Integer.toString(fourthSelection);
        fifthSelectionStr = Integer.toString(fifthSelection);

        //String[] columns = {DBHelper.UID,DBHelper.CNAME};
        //Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ DBHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBHelper.FIRST_ATTRIBUTE + "=? "
                + " AND " + DBHelper.SECOND_ATTRIBUTE + "=? " + " AND " + DBHelper.THIRD_ATTRIBUTE + "=? " + " AND " + DBHelper.FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=? "
                + " AND " + DBHelper.FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=?";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {firstSelectionStr, secondSelectionStr, thirdSelectionStr,
                            fourthSelectionStr, fifthSelectionStr});
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor != null) {

            int tresult = cursor.getCount();

            // Append every data together
            do {
                //int cursorID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.UID));
                String chosenItem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME));
                buffer.append(chosenItem + " ");
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        /*while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            //int cursorID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.UID));
            String chosenItem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME));
            buffer.append(chosenItem + " ");
        }*/
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My crafts in the table have five attributes on them and if an
>   attribute don't exist, it will be 0

**I suspect that you may be making an incorrect assumption and that instead the value inserted when an attribute doesn't exist is null and that defining the attribute columns with DEFAULT 0, may fix the issue**

There are a few factors may affect this;

- COLUMN DEFINITIONS

  - Do the column definitions have a specific default value (DEFAULT 0) rather then the default DEFAULT value which is null.
- INSERT METHODOLOGY

  - When a value isn't assigned do you skip the VALUES not assigned

Otherwise your code works unless no rows are extracted when you will get an **android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0** because you attempt to get data when there is no data in the Cursor.

- i.e you move the Cursor to the first row, which returns false (i.e. move not made) when there are no rows and then check to see if the Cursor is null.
- A Cursor will never be null when it is returned from an SQLiteDatabase method such as rawQuery.

  - The Cursor will always exist and be instantiated (thus not null) and be valid
  - The Cursor will have a row count (the Cursor getCount() method returns integer of the number of rows in the Cursor).

Your query works as expected IF the unassigned values are set to 0.

The following code:-

- Shows that, bar the OutofBounds issue, that your code and query, as shown works if 0's are inserted and attributes are omitted, but not so if nulls are inserted.
- Allows you to see the contents of the tables and if nulls or 0's
- Shows the difference that using DEFAULT 0 makes when attributes are omitted as opposed to set specifically to 0.
- Utilises a second table different only in that DEFAULT 0 is coded in the attribute column definitions.

The **Databasehelper** (with insert methods and also the dumpTable method) :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "mytable2";
    public static final String UID = "uid";
    public static final String CNAME = "cname";
    public static final String FIRST_ATTRIBUTE = "a1";
    public static final String SECOND_ATTRIBUTE = "a2";
    public static final String THIRD_ATTRIBUTE = "a3";
    public static final String FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE = "a4";
    public static final String FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE = "a5";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // Create both tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crt_tbl = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                CNAME + " TEXT, " +
                FIRST_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER, " +
                SECOND_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER," +
                THIRD_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER, " +
                FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER, " +
                FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl);

        String crt_tbl2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2 + "(" +
                UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                CNAME + " TEXT, " +
                FIRST_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
                SECOND_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                THIRD_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
                FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
                FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    }

    // Generic Insert method
    public long insertRow(String table, String cname, int[] attributes) {
        String[] attribute_columns = new String[]{FIRST_ATTRIBUTE,SECOND_ATTRIBUTE,THIRD_ATTRIBUTE,FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE,FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CNAME,cname);
        for (int i=0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
            cv.put(attribute_columns[i],attributes[i]);
        }
        return mDB.insert(table,null,cv);
    }

    // Insert row into table 1 with all 5 attributes
    public long insertRow(String cname,int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5) {
        int[] attributes = new int[]{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5};
        return insertRow(TABLE_NAME,cname,attributes);
    }

    // Inert row in table 1 with first 2 attributes
    public long insertRow(String cname, int a1, int a2) {
        int[] attributes = new int[]{a1,a2};
        return insertRow(TABLE_NAME,cname,attributes);
    }

    // Insert row into table 2 with all 5 atributes
    public long insertRow2(String cname,int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5) {
        int[] attributes = new int[]{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5};
        return insertRow(TABLE_NAME2,cname,attributes);
    }

    // Insert row into table 2 with first 2 attributes
    public long insertRow2(String cname, int a1, int a2) {
        int[] attributes = new int[]{a1,a2};
        return insertRow(TABLE_NAME2,cname,attributes);
    }

    public void dumpTableToLog(String table) {
        Log.d("DUMPTABLE","Dumping table ==>" + table);
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

The Invoking Activity (MainActivity) including your **getData** and an alternative getData2 method :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        //Example table 1 load data

        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null); // Empty table
        dbHelper.insertRow("Crafts", 2, 3, 0, 0, 0);
        dbHelper.insertRow("Arts", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        dbHelper.insertRow("Science", 6, 3, 0, 0, 0);
        dbHelper.insertRow("Maths", 2, 3, 0, 0, 0);
        dbHelper.insertRow("Crafts2",2,3); //<<<<<<<<<< NULLS for a3-a5
        dbHelper.dumpTableToLog(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME); // Dump all table 1 contents to the Log

        Log.d("GETDATAREUSULT", getData(2, 3, 0, 0, 0));
        Log.d("GETDATAREUSULT", getData(1, 3, 0, 0, 0));

        //Example table 2 (with DEFAULT 0) (uses methods ending with 2)

        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null); // Empty table
        dbHelper.insertRow2("Crafts", 2, 3, 0, 0, 0);
        dbHelper.insertRow2("Arts", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        dbHelper.insertRow2("Science", 6, 3, 0, 0, 0);
        dbHelper.insertRow2("Maths", 2, 3, 0, 0, 0);
        dbHelper.insertRow2("Crafts2",2,3); //<<<<<<<<<< NULLS for a3-a5
        dbHelper.dumpTableToLog(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2); // Dump all table 2 contents to the Log

        Log.d("GETDATA2REUSULT", getData2(2, 3, 0, 0, 0));
        Log.d("GETDATA2REUSULT", getData2(1, 3, 0, 0, 0));
    }


    // To get data from DB by querying the items selected
    public String getData(int firstSelection, int secondSelection, int thirdSelection,
                          int fourthSelection, int fifthSelection) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String firstSelectionStr, secondSelectionStr, thirdSelectionStr, fourthSelectionStr, fifthSelectionStr;

        firstSelectionStr = Integer.toString(firstSelection);
        secondSelectionStr = Integer.toString(secondSelection);
        thirdSelectionStr = Integer.toString(thirdSelection);
        fourthSelectionStr = Integer.toString(fourthSelection);
        fifthSelectionStr = Integer.toString(fifthSelection);

        //String[] columns = {DBHelper.UID,DBHelper.CNAME};
        //Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBHelper.FIRST_ATTRIBUTE + "=? "
                + " AND " + DBHelper.SECOND_ATTRIBUTE + "=? " + " AND " + DBHelper.THIRD_ATTRIBUTE + "=? " + " AND " + DBHelper.FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=? "
                + " AND " + DBHelper.FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{firstSelectionStr, secondSelectionStr, thirdSelectionStr,
                fourthSelectionStr, fifthSelectionStr});
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            buffer.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME))).append(" ");
        }
        cursor.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< Should always close cursor when done with it.


        /*
        cursor.moveToFirst(); //<<<<<<<<<< SHOULD ALWAYS CHECK result of move false if unable true if able to move

        if (cursor != null) { //<<<<<<<<<< A cursor return from SQLiteDatabase meyhod will never be null, useless/dangerous

            int tresult = cursor.getCount();

            // Append every data together
            do {
                //int cursorID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.UID));
                String chosenItem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME));
                buffer.append(chosenItem + " ");
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        */
        /*while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            //int cursorID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.UID));
            String chosenItem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME));
            buffer.append(chosenItem + " ");
        }*/

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Alternative using the convenience query method
     * @param firstSelection
     * @param secondSelection
     * @param thirdSelection
     * @param fourthSelection
     * @param fifthSelection
     * @return
     */
    public String getData2(int firstSelection, int secondSelection, int thirdSelection,
                          int fourthSelection, int fifthSelection) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause = DBHelper.FIRST_ATTRIBUTE + "=? AND " +
                DBHelper.SECOND_ATTRIBUTE + "=? AND " +
                DBHelper.THIRD_ATTRIBUTE + "=? AND " +
                DBHelper.FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=? AND " +
                DBHelper.FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=?"
                ;
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{
                String.valueOf(firstSelection),
                String.valueOf(secondSelection),
                String.valueOf(thirdSelection),
                String.valueOf(fourthSelection),
                String.valueOf(fifthSelection)}
                ;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2,
                null,
                whereclause,
                whereargs,
                null,null,null
        );
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            buffer.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME))).append(" ");
        }
        cursor.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< Should always close cursor when done with it.
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

### The results :-

The following is the output to the log

- It should noted that the **first table** (**without DEFAULT 0**) does not select the last row (**Crafts2**) that has nulls for the last three attributes, as per **`D/GETDATAREUSULT: Crafts Maths`**;
- Whilst for the **second table** (**with DEFAULT 0**) that the last row (**Crafts2**) is selected, as per **`D/GETDATA2REUSULT: Crafts Maths Crafts2`**
- The DumpTable shows this last row for the **first table** (attributes 3-5
  as nulls)

  `12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 4 {
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=5
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Crafts2
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=null
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=null
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=null
     12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }`
- For the **second table** as

  `12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 4 {
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=5
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Crafts2
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
  12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }`

:-

```
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? D/DUMPTABLE: Dumping table ==>mytable
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@534b1f2c
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 0 {
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=1
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Crafts
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 1 {
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=2
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Arts
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=1
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=1
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=1
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=1
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=1
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 2 {
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=3
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Science
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=6
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 3 {
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=4
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Maths
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 4 {
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=5
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Crafts2
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=null
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=null
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=null
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.140 1698-1698/? I/System.out: <<<<<
12-01 01:09:12.144 1698-1698/? D/GETDATAREUSULT: Crafts Maths 
12-01 01:09:12.176 1698-1698/? D/DUMPTABLE: Dumping table ==>mytable2
12-01 01:09:12.176 1698-1698/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@534a1c1c
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 0 {
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=1
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Crafts
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 1 {
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=2
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Arts
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=1
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=1
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=1
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=1
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=1
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 2 {
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=3
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Science
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=6
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 3 {
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=4
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Maths
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: 4 {
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    uid=5
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    cname=Crafts2
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a1=2
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a2=3
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a3=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a4=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out:    a5=0
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: }
12-01 01:09:12.180 1698-1698/? I/System.out: <<<<<
12-01 01:09:12.184 1698-1698/? D/GETDATA2REUSULT: Crafts Maths Crafts2
```

Comment: OMG! It fixed it! Thank you so much!!